# SQLite percentages with small values

Tags: sql, sqlite, grouping, percentage

So I have this table of subscribers of users and the country they are in.

```
UserID | Name              | Country
-------+-------------------+------------
1      | Zaphod Beeblebrox | UK
2      | Arthur Dent       | UK
3      | Gene Kelly        | USA
4      | Nat King Cole     | USA
```

I need to produce a list of all the users by percentage from each of the countries. I also need all the smaller member countries (under 1%) to be collapsed into an "OTHERS" category.

I can accomplish a simple "top x" of members trivially with a

```
SELECT COUNTRY, COUNT(*) AS POPULATION FROM SUBSCRIBERS GROUP BY COUNTRY ORDER BY POPULATION DESC LIMIT 10
```

and can generate the percentages by PHP server side code, but I don't quite know how to:

1. Do all of it in SQL including percentage calculations directly in the result
2. Club all under 1% members into a single OTHERS category.

So I need something like this:

```
Country | Population
--------+-----------
USA     | 25.4%
Brazil  | 12%
UK      | 5%
OTHERS  | 65%
```

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think I might have found a way to do this that's a hell of a lot quicker on execution speed:

```
SELECT territory,
       Round(Sum(percentage), 3) AS Population
FROM (SELECT
           Round((Count(*)*100.0)/(SELECT Count(*) FROM subscribers),3) AS Percentage,
           CASE
             WHEN ((Count(*)*100.0)/(SELECT Count(*) FROM subscribers)) > 2 THEN
             country
             ELSE 'Other'
           END AS Territory
      FROM   subscribers
      GROUP  BY country
      ORDER  BY percentage DESC)
GROUP  BY territory
ORDER  BY population DESC;
```

Comment: I was under the assumption you wanted ‘Other’ to be sorted last, which is quite common in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is query for this, I used a subquery to count the total number of rows and then used that to get the percentage value for each. The 'Others' category was generated in a separate query. Rows are sorted by descending population with the Others row last.

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT country , ROUND((100.0*COUNT(*)/count_all),1) ||'%' AS population
     FROM (SELECT count(*) count_all FROM subscribers) AS sq,
     subscribers s
     WHERE (SELECT 100*count(*)/count_all 
            FROM subscribers s2 
            WHERE s2.country = s.country) > 1
     GROUP BY country
     ORDER BY population DESC)
UNION ALL
SELECT 'OTHERS', IFNULL(ROUND(100.0*COUNT(*)/count_all,1),0.0) ||'%' AS population
FROM (SELECT count(*) count_all FROM subscribers) AS sq,
     subscribers s
WHERE (SELECT 100*count(*)/count_all 
       FROM subscribers s2 
       WHERE s2.country = s.country) <= 1
```

Comment: Just had a go at it. The query seems to take a super long time to run. The subscriber table has about 75000 entries. It does work however so its a great starting point! Let me try and put a few indexes on those columns to see if it speeds it up.